# How to present a viewController modally when it's tabBar item is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a `UITabBarController` and 5 `UITabBarItem`s. I would like to launch modally a View Controller for the third tab-bar item (camera controller).

I tried this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  self.presentViewController(self, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

But my app crashed. What should I do?

Comment: You need to do it in viewDidAppear. Any earlier, and the view will not yet be in the window's view hierarchy.

Comment: crash in viewDidAppear with this error : "Application tried to present modally an active controller"

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you're trying to present "self". Why would you do that? Self is already on screen.

Comment: ok, so how could i make it appear modally, before it is onscreen ?

Comment: You don't. That makes no sense. If you want to present it modally, then it shouldn't be one of the tab bar controller's children. You need to rethink your UI.

Comment: Instagram does it with it s camera controller. There is a solution. Maybe in appDelegate, detecting witch tabBar item is selected and the present the VC modally ?

Comment: No, you can't present a controller that's already active. You could create another instance of that same controller, and present it. Why you would want to do that, I don't know, but you could do it.

Comment: @jmcastel did you get it to work by any chance I am trying to do something similar....

Answer (score 0):

If you want a floating center button (or something similar) you basically need an empty tab that is used as a placeholder for a custom button that you add at specific coordinates.

This new button you add as a subview of the tabbar and simply open your modal dialog from the user pressing it. The space it requires on the tabbar is provided by the empty and disabled item below it. Other than providing the parent view the tabbarcontroller has nothing to do with it. If you set the tab image as nil, title as empty and disable it then it is just empty space where you can put your own button.